# Manually loaded configuration script leads to a weird path behavior

Tags: python

I've created a small command line utility. I would like to let users customize the behavior of the command by setting the path to a python script, however when I load this script using:

```
import imp
my_script = imp.load_source('script', script_path)
```

However the import within the script are not working anymore, what was working before now fails with `No module named lib`

```
import mycommand.lib as my_lib
```

Here is the structures of my files:

```
mycommand/
    __init__.py
    command.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
external_script/
    __init__.py
    script.py
```

I do my tests typing:

```
python mycommand/command.py external_script/script.py
```

I hope I'm clear enough. I'm running Python 2.7.

Comment: How `import mycommand.lib` was succesful, and where it is now?

Comment: It has been removed because I want to load my script using `imp`.

Answer (score 0):

imp.load_source() first argument is the name you want the script to be imported as, in your case it's being called 'script'. Probably will work if you change 'script' to 'mycommand'?

Comment: I made it more or less work by changing the import to `import lib`, I still don't get why this is required and the module named command.lib seems to be missing.